# Baking pretzels in a muffin tin?

Tags: baking, muffins, pretzels

I'd like to make something like pretzel buns/bites in a muffin tin. Could I just take a normal pretzel recipe, skip the rolling step, put the dough balls in the baking soda bath as usual, and then bake them in muffin cups? If not, what would I need to change?

Comment: What do you mean by "skip the rolling step"? You always have the same number of shaping/rising steps for all breads, no matter if you bake them freeform or in a shaped tin.

Comment: I mean the step where you roll the dough into a pretzel shape.

Comment: This may need some explanation of your country. In Germany, pretzel (Brezen) are defined by their shape and anything else in an alkali bath is considered lye baked goods (Laugengebäck) but not pretzel. In the USA, the word pretzel is used for the lye bath, independent of shape, and the semiknotted shape is rarely seen in bread, they usually make "pretzel rolls" instead. Which one do you mean in your question? What happens in the "rolling step" you refer to? I usually hear the word "rolling" for dough in connection with a rolling pin, and this is not done for either meaning of pretzel.

Comment: I guess I'm not entirely clear on the difference between making pretzel rolls vs. traditional pretzels--I assumed it was mostly a question of shape and not an actual change in recipe. By rolling step I meant something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpOfYie-JeU), where the pretzel is being formed into the traditional shape.